# __iregex=searchterm not working in django

Tags: python, regex, django

I have this query:

```
q = MyModel.objects.filter(title__iregex=r"\y{0}\y".format(searchterm))
```

but once I give `c++` as searchterm, i am getting this error:

```
Error:  invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
```

how can I make signs like `+, /, -, %` passable thru regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape them: `c\+\+`.  Maybe escape them twice, if sth is evaluating one escaping:  `c\\+\\+`.

If you want to do that programmatically, use `re.escape()`:

```
import re

print re.escape('c++')
```

This will print

```
c\+\+
```

Comment: thanks, but it is becoming ``c\+\+``. how can i get only ``c++`` from this? i did ``re.escape(re.escape('c++'))`` but it is becoming ``c\\+\\+``

Comment: That's what escaping means.  If you search for a regexp `c\+\+` you will find occurrences of `c++`.  Maybe you should learn about escaping of special characters by reading things like [this WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Comment: i am wondering then why it doesnot find the objects that have ``c++`` in title. there are some of them in db.. i saw in console that the form is sending it as c++.